# 404 Not Found in autocomplete in laravel

Tags: laravel, jquery-ui, autocomplete, laravel-5

So I'm trying to implement a simple autocompletion using jquery ui in my laravel 5.2 app. But I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the input field:

```
<input id="participants" name="participants" type="text">
```

My javascript

```
$("#participants").autocomplete({
    source: "/user/get-users-json",
    minLength: 1
});
```

My route:

```
Route::get('user/get-users-json', 'UsersController@getUsersJson');
```

My getUsersJson method:

```
public function getUsersJson() {

$term = strtolower(Input::get('participants'));

$data = array('John', 'James', 'Henry', 'Graham', 'Mitthew', 'Rick', 'Tom');

$return_array = array();

foreach ($data as $value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($value), $term) !== false) {
        $return_array[] = array('value' => $value);
    }
}
return response()->json($return_array);
}
}
```

When I submit the form to /user/get-users-json, it works perfectly and prints the JSON I need to the webpage but the autocompletion itself doesn't work and I have no idea why.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the GET parameter that is sent by jquery ui is "term", not "participants". So I changed from getUsersJson method

```
$term = strtolower(Input::get('participants'));
```

to

```
$term = strtolower(Input::get('term'));
```

And it worked!

Comment: Yes indeed, JQuery autocomplete adds a query string with a `term` field to the source url, not the name of the `input` tag. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to reach the url `user/get-users-json`, the browser thinks you want to do it in the current directory. You can see in the error that it's trying to reach `/event/user/get-users-json` and not the one you want.

Change it to `source: "/user/get-users-json",` with a slash in the beginning to tell the browser to append the route to the base instead. That should be enough to make it work.

Comment: Now I'm getting 500 (Internal server error). Yet, if the form is submitted normally I receive the json I want.

Comment: Then I'm willing to bet that you don't have your ajax csrf tokens in order, so the server can't validate the request when you send it using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have typo in your JavaScript function

```
$("#participants").autocomplete({
    source: "/user/get-users-json", // use absolute path starting with slash
    minLength: 1
 });
```

Hope it works